# Почему когда в коде выставляю определённый размер шрифта в браузере он отображается совсем другим?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Иммется наипростейшая html страница с несколькими эл-ми. В браузере размер шрифта по умолчанию 18px. Когда в коде принудительно для body задаю 10px браузер отображает 11,333px, для 20px следовательно 22,667px, т.е. коэффициент на который браузер домнажает размер указанный в коде равняется 1,1333. И всё бы хорошо, но когда сделал шрифт равным 30px размер в браузере уже был 34,667 и коэффициент получился равным 1,1556, а при 40px браузер показал 46px и коэффициент всвязи с этим был 1,15. Изменял размер шрифта у текста просто в body и в элементах, вкладывал элементы одни в другие, но результат всё тот же. Как же так получается, как добиться того чтобы размеры отображаемые в браузере точно соотвествовали размерам установленным в коде. Это несоответствие очень мешает вёрстке, особено когда дело начинает касаться относительных величин типа rem и em. Ниже приложил скриншот на котором чётко видно это не соответсвие для заголовка в коде установлен размер 40px а в браузере 46px. [image: Несоответсвие размера шрифта в коде и браузере]. Исследование проводил в браузере chrome, но opera даёт такие же результаты. Быть может в других браузерах всё иначе. Сам код приложить не получилось, поэтому также прикрепляю и скриншот кода:[image: Код страницы]
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему, быть может есть какая-то формула по которой вычисляются эти размеры браузером, или документация в которой объясняется почему всё так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размер шрифта (font-size) и размер элемента - это разные вещи. Также на размер влияет высота строки (line-height)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошое свойство line-height, прекрасно работает как с абсолютными так и с относительными величинами, благодарю что указали на него